# Linux shell script delete/restore/trash part 2

Tags: bash, shell

Thank you in advance for any help, this is coursework so further reading/ pointers is greatly appreciated.

I asked a question the other day relating to my own delete/trash/restore scripts and I have completed delete and trash as well as giving delete a backup text file for Restore to use later on.

However, instead of giving me errors, the Restore script just kinda stops in the console. Like when I type # ~/Restore -n     the cursor skips to the next line without the usual # and I have to close it manually. Likewise without the -n option. The -n option should ask for a new location to restore to, and without it should restore to the files original location.
 I'll post my script, see what y'all think.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]
then  cd ~/rubbish
  restore= grep $2 ~/store      
  filename= basename "$restore"
  echo "Type the files new location"
  read location
  location1 = "readlink -f $location"       
  mv -i $filename "$location1" /$filename       
else  cd ~/rubbish          
  restore= grep $2 ~/store      
  filename= basename "$restore"         
  mv -i $filename "$location1" $location            
fi
```

so, ~/rubbish is my own created directory to act as a recycle bin and ~/store is my text file which appends the deleted files readlink details on deletion.   I can post the whole 3 scripts if necessary?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `~/Restore -n` it will go to the `if` part and do a `grep $2 ~/store`. Since there is no parameter `$2` it will result in `grep ~/store`, which tells grep to search for "~/store" in the input coming from standard input.

That's why your script stops and waits for input.

You can either test for a second parameter or enclose `$2` in double quotes to make sure grep gets the correct number of parameters. Better yet, do both: 1. test for a second parameter *and* 2. enclose $2 in double quotes.

Some more points:

- Don't put spaces around `=`
- enclose commands in backticks `, if you want to capture the output
- And no spaces between directory and filename

So, you should presumably write

```
restore=`grep "$2" ~/store`
filename=`basename "$restore"`
echo "Type the files new location"
read location
location1=`readlink -f "$location"`
mv -i $filename "$location1/$filename"
```

I suggest you look at [bash info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) and follow the "Books and Resources".

Comment: I kinda thought that calling from console like ~/Restore -n ~/Rubbish/NewFile would pass the file to be restored as a second parameter $2? I'll try your sugestions though! Thanks!

Comment: @Moominboy Yes, it does. But that's not what you wrote in your question: "when I type # ~/Restore -n". Then your problem might be something different. Call your script as `bash -x ~/Restore -n ~/Rubbish/NewFile` and post the output or at least the last few lines.

Comment: @Moominboy I looked more closely at your script and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one of these quite some time ago which I still use today. I don't have a restore script because I wrote it so that you could open your desktop trash can, right click and select "Restore". In other words it follows the Linux "trash info" standard.

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Scripting#KDE4_Command_Line_Trash_Can